# How to avoid collision between optional arguments and options?

Tags: function-construction, options, optional-arguments

Is it possible to create a function with optional arguments that also takes options?

Here is a simple example. I have a function `f` with option "g". It also has optional arguments `y` and `z` which are set to default values.

```
Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};

f[x_, y_: 2, z_: 3, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]
```

Now, if I give values for all of the arguments and an option value it works just fine.

```
In[3]:= f[1, 2, 3, "g" -> (#^2 &)]

Out[3]= 36
```

If I give only the required argument, no problems.

```
In[4]:= f[1]

Out[4]= 6
```

However, if I give the required arg and an option value but don't give the optional arguments, I run into trouble..

```
In[5]:= f[1, "g" -> (#^2 &)]

Out[5]= 4 + ("g" -> (#1^2 &))
```

Is there a good way around this?

**EDIT:**

Obviously, it is possible to write multiple definitions...

```
f[x_, y_, z_, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]

f[x_, y_, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["g"][x + y + 3]

f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["g"][x + 2 + 3]
```

I'm curious if there is a clean way to do it with a single definition.

Comment: I tend to do the construction `f[(* optional arguments *), (* required arguments *), (* options *)]` myself... is there a reason you can't move optional arguments to the front?

Comment: @JM when writing code for others (as I often do) it is typical to reserve the first arg for the most critical input, say the data in a statistical test and leave the remaining args for extra tweaking. Thus, the ordering is important. I typically write multiple definitions but was wondering if it is possible to do in one go.

Comment: There's also the possibility of strict typing for your optional arguments. If your optional arguments cannot have the head `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`, the typing would prevent options being interpreted as optional arguments...

Comment: @JM I often use `arg_?(Not[OptionQ[#]]&)` to cover the `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` cases.  This doesn't work though if I have optional args with default settings.

Comment: See my answer for how I believe that pattern can be used.

Comment: Related discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/35ff6cf97d5019ec

Comment: According to named conventions of Wolfram Language there are two categories of optional arguments, those that are explicitly named using transformation rules and those where their semantics are dependent on their position. The second method allows one to drop arguments, replacing them by default values and the first allows to specify default rules in the Options (see also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html)

Comment: This distinction between "positional" and "named" arguments is also a fundamental problem of data modeling in tuples representation. There is the relational database model where you have tuples of ordered values, and there is the RDF, JSON, Wolfram Association, Wolfram Rules, where you represent members of the tuple with key-value pairs. It seems there is a way to combine these two in data modeling !

Comment: OptionsPattern needs to be improved!

Comment: There are tons of posts attempting to work around a flaw with MMA in which arguments clash with `Options`. There are even two new symbols, `ArgumentsOptions` and `CheckArguments`, which try to correct that. All I'm saying is how hard can it be for MMA to only take those arguments as `Options` that were previously defined as such? If it's a `Rule` with the name of a previously defined `Option` for this `Symbol` then it's an `Option` not an argument. Shouldn't this be a no-brainer, Wolfram?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Mathematica has to be able to tell that the default arguments can't be rules. So, for some special cases, you could do

```
Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};

f[x_, y_Integer: 2, z_Integer: 3, OptionsPattern[]]:= OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]
```

Testing:

```
f[1, 2, 3, "g" -> (#^2 &)]
```

> ```
> 36
> ```

```
f[1]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
f[1, "g" -> (#^2 &)]
```

> ```
> 36
> ```

Comment: Is it time for `OptionsObject`? .. . entered via keyboard shortcuts and or: `<o| "g"-> Identity |o>` . [The small `o` looked better than cap]

Answer (score 34):

Here is another method that I learned through reading [*Inside the Mathematica Pattern Matcher*](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6999/):

```
Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};

f[x_,
  Shortest[y_: 2, 1],
  Shortest[z_: 3, 2],
  OptionsPattern[] 
 ] := OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]
```

From the documentation for `Shortest`:

> **Shortest[*p*, *pri*]** is given priority *pri* to be the shortest sequence.
>   Matches for shortest sequences are tried first for Shortest objects
>   with higher priorities.

Comment: This is maybe the most elegant answer.

Comment: @FJRA thank you.  I thought it was worthy of its own post as it is unrelated to my first method(s).  Also, welcome to the site. :-)

Answer (score 29):

*Edit: better answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1690/121).*

I voted for Rojo's answer.  If for some reason you cannot be that specific about your arguments you might use the converse:

```
nr = Except[_?OptionQ];

f[x_, y : nr : 2, z : nr : 3, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]
```

If for some further reason you need the optional arguments to be rules themselves, you could filter out specifically valid options:

```
Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};

notOpts = 
  Except[Alternatives @@ Replace[Options[f], h_[a_, _] :> h[a, _], 1]];

f[x_, y : notOpts : 2, z : notOpts : 3, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  {OptionValue["g"], x, y, z}

f[1, "a" -> 7, "g" -> "g value"]
```

> ```
> {"g value", 1, "a" -> 7, 3}
> ```

Comment: @MrWizard This is pretty cool, why does this work when `nr = x_/;!OptionQ[x]` does not?

Comment: @Andy `Condition` applies to the entire function pattern.  Think about `f[1, 2, x_ /; x > 5] := ...` and `f[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @MrWizard I guess I'm just not getting it.. its 2:00 am here so that may be why :) What I'm seeing from your example is obvious, the 3rd arg will not admit anything smaller than 5. But !OptionQ will exclude only Rule, {}, and RuleDelayed, (I think).

Comment: @Andy I mean that if the condition fails the entire definition of `f` does not match.

Comment: @Andy I was wrong.  See kguler's answer below.

Comment: @AndyRoss, as to your `nr = x_/;!OptionQ[x]`, according to The Standard Evaluation Procedure, in `f[x_,y:nr:2,z:nr:3,OptionsPattern[]]:=...`, the patterns `x_,y:nr:2,z:nr:3,OptionsPattern[]` will firstly be evaluated in order. If any of the `y` or `z` `Condition` fails then the entire definition of `f` will be considered unmatched and the follwing `SetDelayed` will not be applied. As a result, if we call `f[1,"g"->(#^2&)]` then the `"g"->(#^2&)` will firstly be checked with the `y:nr:2` which yields unmatch.

Comment: Something that bit me in the past about optional arguments and options was not noticing that `OptionsPattern[]` can match not only a sequence of options, but also any nested list of options.  Luckily, `OptionQ` also returns true for such lists!  Thus this is not a loophole in your method.  But the discovery that `OptionQ[{a->1, b->2}]` is `True` is new to me.  EDIT:  Well, it's pretty clearly stated in the usage messages, but I didn't look there ...

Comment: Didn't know about `OptionQ`, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

A bit late-to-the-party post, and complementary to the other solutions. Several answers addressed the question quite well IMO. I had my shot on a similar one [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/35ff6cf97d5019ec), with a solution similar to the one by @Mr.Wizard. But now I just want to stress one subtle point missed by other answers: using `OptionQ` will leak evaluation for functions which are `HoldAll` *and*  take optional arguments and options. As an example, consider a modified solution of @Mr.Wizard:

```
ClearAll[f];
nr = Except[_?OptionQ];
Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
With[{nr = nr},
  f[x_, y : nr : 2, z : nr : 3, OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["g"][Hold[x + y + z]]
]
```

Note by the way that we had here to inject `nr`. In my solution in the linked Mathgroup thread, I used `notOptionQ[x_] := ! OptionQ[x];`, and the patterns looked like `_?notOptionQ`, so for this one injecting is unnecessary. In any case, try this code:

```
f[1, Print["*"], "g" -> 10]
```

You will see that printing happens as a part of the pattern-matching procedure. To avoid that, one should use this pattern instead:

```
nr = Except[_?(Function[elem, OptionQ[Unevaluated[elem]], HoldAll])];
```

Parentheses around `Function` are mandatory, and injecting is still required in this approach. The `f` redefined with this pattern does not leak evaluation:

```
f[1, Print["*"], "g" -> 10]

(*
  ==> 10[Hold[1 + Print["*"] + 3]]
*)
```

Admittedly, the case of `Hold*`-functions is not that often in practice, but I thought this subtlety should be mentioned here as well.

Comment: As always you take it to another level.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! So, back the the good old name? I must admit I got used to Mr.Wizard and the transition to Spartacus in our correspondence wasn't easy, so I am happy now. Congrats with becoming a mod, by the way! This will surely help make this site a better place.

Comment: Thank you Leonid.  I always intended to switch back.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another possibility that makes use of a more involved pattern to delimit the arguments from the options. It seems to me that people writing "function definitions" are inclined to think of them rigidly in that way, commonly forgetting that these are still just patterns and can be used (and abused) as such. However, bearing in mind the true nature of these definitions can be useful in circumstances like this:

```
Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};

Module[{argumentDelimiter},
 SetAttributes[argumentDelimiter, HoldAllComplete]; (* thanks Leonid! *)
 f[args : Shortest[___], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  f[argumentDelimiter[args], opts];
 f[argumentDelimiter[x_: 1, y_: 2, z_: 3], OptionsPattern[]] := 
  OptionValue["g"][x + y + z];
];
```

(As you can see, I made the first argument optional as well for didactic purposes.)

It seems to work well enough:

```
In[3] := f[]

Out[3] = 6

In[4] := f["g" -> Internal`Square] (* ;) *)

Out[4] = 36

In[5] := f[3, 3, "g" -> Sqrt]

Out[5] = 3

In[6] := f[1, 17, "pianoforte" -> "harpsichord", "g" -> Sqrt]
         OptionValue::nodef: "Unknown option pianoforte for f." >>

Out[6] = Sqrt[21]
```

In fact, I wasn't able to trip this method up at all, which makes me slightly suspicious that I didn't try enough test cases. Can anyone else point out some shortcomings of this approach?

#### Edit

In response @Mr.Wizard's comments, I thought it best to clarify the following:

> Why use `argumentDelimiter`, rather than `Hold` or `HoldComplete`?

Because `argumentDelimiter` is created inside a `Module`, its uniqueness can be guaranteed. As a result there is no possibility for conflict when one wishes to define functions that accept arguments wrapped with `Hold` etc. This approach is commonly seen in packages, although in that case a suitable symbol will usually be created in the `` package`Private` ``  context once and for all rather than relying on `Module` because of the associated overheads.

> Isn't `Shortest` redundant?

In principle, yes; however, since `OptionsPattern[]` may also make use of `Shortest`, in my opinion it is better to avoid unexpected conflicts by explicitly requiring the shortest possible sequence of arguments. As documented for `Shortest`, in case of two competing `Shortest` patterns appearing in the same expression, the one that appears first has higher priority, so anything that can match `OptionsPattern[]` always will in this case.

> What if the optional but non-option arguments also happen to match `OptionsPattern[]`?

In this case one has problems regardless of using this technique, and I would consider it to be a limitation of `OptionsPattern[]` that invalid options also match. To avoid this situation, one must use @Mr.Wizard's suggestion instead of `OptionsPattern[]`, i.e.:

```
validOptionsPattern[f_] := 
  Alternatives @@ 
    Replace[Options[f], (h : (Rule | RuleDelayed))[opt_, _] :> h[opt, _], 1] ...;
```

The approach then becomes:

```
Module[{argumentDelimiter}, 
 SetAttributes[argumentDelimiter, HoldAllComplete];
 f[args : Shortest[Except[_argumentDelimiter] ...], opts : validOptionsPattern[f]] :=
  f[argumentDelimiter[args], opts];
 f[argumentDelimiter[x_: 1, y_: 2, z_: 3], OptionsPattern[]] := 
  OptionValue["g"][x + y + z];
];
```

Note that `Options[f]` must be set before evaluating this definition so that `validOptionsPattern[f]` has the correct value. (At least for the time being, because making a `validOptionsPattern[]` that works exactly like `OptionsPattern[]` except for validating the options seems to be non-trivial.)

So, first with `Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity}`:

```
In[5] := f[1, 17, "pianoforte" -> "harpsichord", "g" -> Sqrt]

Out[5] = Sqrt[18 + ("pianoforte" -> "harpsichord")] (* treated as argument *)
```

And now with `Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity, "clarinet" -> "vuvuzela"}`:

```
In[10] := f[1, 17, "clarinet" -> "vuvuzela", "g" -> Sqrt]

Out[10] = Sqrt[21] (* option accepted *)
```

So everything appears to work correctly. However, if your optional arguments could also be interpreted as valid option values, I would consider that situation ill-defined and as such outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: +1.  I would add however that depending on one's perspective, your own `In[6] :=` lines shows this "tripping up" which is why I provided the methods that I did.

Comment: Also, what is the reason for using `argumentDelimiter` rather than `Hold` or `HoldComplete`?

Comment: Actually, isn't `Shortest` the default behavior and therefore redundant?

Comment: @MrWizard In principle `Shortest` should be redundant but I don't know if `OptionsPattern[]` makes use of `Shortest`, so per the documentation of `Shortest` (first `Shortest` wins) I used it anyway. And I used a unique symbol to avoid conflicts with functions that take `Hold`/`HoldComplete` as part of their normal arguments.

Comment: I agree that this is normal behavior.  I was simply looking at the corner case where one of the named arguments should be in the form of a rule, as you asked us to point out shortcomings and it's the only one I can see.

Comment: Good stuff - +1. I often use `Hold` or `HoldComplete` to simply separate options from arguments, like `f[Hold[x_,y_,x_],opts:OptionsPattern]`. This allows me to not make `f` `HoldAll` (assuming I want to hold `x`,`y` and `z`). The advantage is that I can call it as `f[Hold[a,b,c],opts]` and this will match if `opts` stores some options. Otherwise, I'd have to make `f` `HoldAll` and call it as `f[a,b,c,Evaluate[opts]`, and in practice it is very easy to forget `Evaluate` and get bugs, particularly if I expose the function to the user, who can not be expected to remember about `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 12):

I too like Rojo's answer. And Mr. Wizard's answer is intriguing as always. A third possibility is adding the condition that the `Head`s of second and third arguments are not `Rule` after the LHS. So, the following also works

```
 Options[f] = {"g" -> Identity};
 f[x_, y_: 2, z_: 3,  OptionsPattern[]] /; (Head[y] =!= Rule && Head[z] =!= Rule):= 
 OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]
```

The condition could be alternatively stated as `(OptionQ[y] =!= True && OptionQ[z] =!= True)`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, hope the new condition works?

Comment: I didn't think that would work.  I like being proven wrong: it's embarrassing but I learn from it. +1

Comment: Thanks @kglr, I have read through all the answers and found that yours is the most elegant and efficient. For other answers , either it does not work anymore since `OptionQ` does not exist in recent versions of MMA and there is even no items related `OptionQ` in online documentation, or its algorithm complexity is much more greater than yours. Just now I ran a test on my computer using your solution to modify my program and it gave me a all-success. Pitifully I am not the poster, so I can only vote up your solution. If I were the poster, I would definitely accept your answer as the best!

Comment: @AlbertLew, thank you for the vote and kind words. `OptionQ`  works in recent versions too (I tried version 11.3.0 and version 13.0.1). It is still not documented but `Information @ OptionQ`  gives sufficient info.

Comment: I see. In my previous belief, if a built-in function cannot be found in the latest documentation then it is obsolete , not working anymore and might have been replaced by some other new built-in function. Never thought there are functions like `OptionQ` which is built-in , not documented but still works! A nice learning experience :). By the way, even those solutions with `OptionQ` still works, their algorithm efficiencies still lag far behind yours. Good Job!@kglr

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick nobody mentioned yet is to use `PatternSequence` for your positional arguments:

`f[PatternSequence[x_, y_ : 2, z_ : 3], OptionsPattern[]]`

Why it works, though? No idea :). I hate how `Optional` and `Default` works in general, it doesn't make sense to me in many many cases.