# Why doesn't PatternTest work with Composition?

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching

While playing around with the solutions to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/129), I've found some very strange behaviour:

```
MatchQ[3,_?Composition[Not,OptionQ]]
(*
==> False
*)
MatchQ[3,_?(Not[OptionQ[#]]&)]
(*
==> True
*)
Composition[Not,OptionQ][3]
(*
==> True
*)
```

So what's wrong with the first pattern? Or did I just find some bug?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because `PatternTest` binds very tightly. You need extra parentheses:

```
MatchQ[3, _?(Composition[Not, OptionQ])]
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that possibility myself ...

Comment: @celtschk This is not at all obvious - it binds stronger than a function call: `a?f[b] // FullForm` gives `PatternTest[a,f][b]`, which is not something we are used to. I just happened to have been bitten by this a few times. The same story with the `Function`: have to wrap it in parentheses as well. I actually mentioned that in my answer to the question you linked.

Comment: This is one reason I tend to use `Condition` for anything that isn't completely trivial...

Comment: @Brett I use `PatternTest` in this form with parentheses quite a bit as well, but I agree that there are less chances for errors with `Condition`.

Comment: It's unusual for something to have a higher precedence than `[...]` function call ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, that's what I also said in the comments. This is why this can be very puzzling.

Comment: As another example of this behavior, note that
a_b[c] // FullForm
->Pattern[a,Blank[b]][c]

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom That's a good point. But this is probably less frequent use case.