# Why can't NumberQ be used as the head of a pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Consider the following:

```
list={1/First[{}], 1, 2, 1/First[{}], 3};
DeleteCases[list,_NumberQ]
```

I wanted to remove all cases, which did not match `_!NumberQ` (e.g. `1/First[{}]`), in the first place. But after `DeleteCases[list,_!NumberQ]` did not work, I tried it with `DeleteCases[list,_NumberQ]`, just to see whether that would work...didn't.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: NumberQ is a predicate function so to make a pattern you need _?NumberQ

Comment: just curious... is there a reason you unaccepted mine?

Comment: R.M., sorry, I thought I did. Sorry!

Comment: @John Have you considered if one of the answers can be accepted ?  I would suggest to accept R.M.'s answer, but you can do whatever you would like and I think the both answers give good solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax `_foo` indicates that you're looking for a pattern with the head `foo`. [`NumberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberQ.html) is **not** a `Head`, but a test returning a boolean `True` or `False` depending on whether the expression is a number or not. So you'd have to use it with [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) as `_?NumberQ`. For your example, the following should work:

```
Cases[list, _?NumberQ]
```

If you wanted to stick with `DeleteCases`, then you'll have to negate the test using either of the three constructs below:

```
DeleteCases[list, _?(Composition[Not, NumberQ])]
DeleteCases[list, _?(! NumberQ[#] &)]
DeleteCases[list, Except[_?NumberQ]]
```

Beware that `?` has a very high precedence and binds very tightly and hence the parentheses are necessary in the first two constructs. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/5) for more info.

Comment: Here another `DeleteCases`-issue:

{{"Bla1","Bla2","Bla3","Bla4"}, {-0.81682, 
  0.373522}, {0.373522, -0.451794}}
DeleteCases[%, {# > 0, # < 0} &]

I fear, that I still have a great lack of basic knowledge... :-/

Comment: @John This example better fits to use of `Select`, look at  my answer.

Comment: @Artes: This is really odd. I swear I didn't unaccepted it. Sorry, though.

Comment: @John I think you're confused here. You can "accept" only one answer, not both. When you check more than one answer, the checkmark gets removed from the previous answer, thereby "unaccepting" it. You can see this in the [timeline](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/3486/timeline), where you first accepted mine, then Artes', then mine again and back to Artes'. Generally, people accept the answer that is clear and was helpful to them. In cases of competing answers, different users have different ways to decide whose to pick — votes/clarity/elegance/coin-toss... You gotta pick yours :)

Comment: Just a small nitpicking here: `NumberQ` **is** a head, just like any other symbol, e.g. see: `Quiet@Cases[{2, NumberQ[], 1, NumberQ[1]}, _NumberQ]`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar That's a rather... contrived example :D I'm not sure if syntactically incorrect examples count, but point taken, nevertheless :)

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following :

```
Cases[list, _?NumberQ]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[list, Except[_?NumberQ]]
```

you could also use :

```
DeleteCases[list, Except[_?NumericQ]]
```

**Edit**

The reason one misuses `DeleteCases` is because there are similar constructs which work like this (giving the same result) :

```
Select[list, NumberQ]
```

i.e. `Select[list, criterion]`  picks out elements of the list for which `criterion` is `True` unlike `DeleteCases[list, pattern]` which removes elements of `list` that match given a pattern. `DeleteCases` is supposed to work with expressions, while `Select` works basically with lists, although list can have any head, not only `List`.

`NumberQ` is a more restictive function than `NumericQ`, since the latter gives `True` also for symbols like e.g. `E` :

```
Head /@ {E, N[E]}
```

> {Symbol, Real}

```
{NumberQ[E], NumericQ[E]}
```

> {False, True}

Comment: `NumberQ` and `NumericQ` are not the same. For example: `Through[{NumberQ, NumericQ}@π]`

Comment: `NumberQ` and `NumericQ` do the same work for this kind of list, however they may yield different results in general.

Comment: I never said you should remove your answer :) I merely observed that identical solutions were posted merely 2 seconds apart. I've never had such a close call, although I've seen closer

Comment: I don't find your answers unhelpful at all! I think I've voted for most of them.

Comment: @R.M Thank You ! Nevertheless I see I could improve most of my answers  but in general I try to avoid to many edits. On the other hand I learn mainly when I try to give answers, even though I don't have them right now.