# How can one match a function in a replacement rule

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I'm trying to write a delayed replacement rule that is capable of matching both the functions and their parameters, like

```
h[1, k[2, x]] /. {f[n_, g[m_, x] _] _ :> f[0, g[m + n, x]]}
```

The idea would be that I get the output `h[0,k[3,x]]` for the example I give here. However, obviously the point is that I want the rule to also match, for example `f[3,g[5,x]]` and give the answer `f[0,g[8,x]]`. Is it possible to write such a rule?

Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(2449)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121), [(3486)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3486/121), [(18170)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18170/121), [(68823)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68823/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the underscore after the name of the `Head` instead of after the final square brackets,

```
h[1, k[2, x]] /. {f_[n_, g_[m_, x] ] :> f[0, g[m + n, x]]}
(* h[0, k[3, x]] *)

f[3, g[5, x]] /. {f_[n_, g_[m_, x] ] :> f[0, g[m + n, x]]}
(* f[0, g[8, x]] *)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I was getting myself confused because I was also trying to apply a match to the functions like `f_?opQ[m_,g_?opQ[n_,x]]`, for a defined function opQ, so I tried the underscore straight after f and g, and at the end, but didn't try at the front without the extra rule. Then it seems the rule is added after, so `f_[m_,g_[n_,x]?opQ]?opQ` finally does what I need. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad I could help!