# Parentheses in pure functions: # & vs. ( # &)

Tags: functions, syntax

I've been using *Mathematica* for years, and over time I have developed the habit of using:

```
Select[data, (# == 1 &)]
```

instead of

```
Select[data, # == 1 &]
```

I learned this by mimicking the style of more experienced users. I'm pretty sure that there are reasons for flanking the function with parentheses, but I'm not sure that I have seen a reason for why this is necessary or a good habit to get into.  Would someone be able to comment?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is a good habit to get into because you can often get tripped up by [precedence rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) (no one remembers everything!). For instance, [`PatternTest` binds very tightly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/5). See the difference between these two definitions:

```
Clear@f
f[_?(# == 2 &)] := Print@"foo"
f[_] := Print@"bar"
f[2]
(* "foo" *)

Clear@g
g[_?# == 2 &] := Print@"foo"
g[_] := Print@"bar"
g[2]
(* "bar" *)
```

You can see that the second function does not behave as expected. Further inspection of the patterns will show that the function is not being defined as expected:

```
_?#1 == 2 & // FullForm
(* Function[Equal[PatternTest[Blank[],Slot[1]],2]] *)

_?(#1 == 2 &) // FullForm
(* PatternTest[Blank[],Function[Equal[Slot[1],2]]] *)
```

A similar situation arises when you're supplying a pure function to options such as `ColorFunction`, `Mesh`, etc.

Comment: On the other hand, I probably wouldn't use parentheses in functions like `Select` or `Split` unless needed.

Comment: Another typical grr-case is in rules, like `ColorFunction -> 3 # &`

Comment: "There is no parenthesis shortage yet; if the parentheses clarify your code's intent, don't hesitate to put them in."

Answer (score 23):

I like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to discover how it's grouped. For example, in this example:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> Hue[#] &]
```

Putting your cursor position after `&` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> two times, you will get all expression `ColorFunction -> Hue[#]` marked, so it's wrong, and you need to put () like this:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#] &)]
```

And now, if you do the same test, you get just `Hue[#] &`marked, that is what we need.

In your example (`Select[data, # == 1 &]`) you can test and see that you get the right grouped form, so it's not necessary.

Comment: I use the same method, [among others](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121). +1

Comment: @Murta It is a nice approach. Could you please kindly explain what in general makes this Ctrl+Dot operation? Not only in regard to this particular problem, but in a more general context.

Answer (score 17):

R.M chose `PatternTest` as an example but I find that subtly misleading.  PatternTest is highly unusual because it binds tighter than `[ ]`, meaning `x_?head[arg]` parses as `(x_?head)[arg]`, but even without this behavior the parentheses would be needed.

In your own example the parentheses are unnecessary and, being a fan of terse coding, I suggest you leave them out unless the bounds of your function are unclear.  There is no ambiguity in `Select[ data, # == 1 & ]` and it is easy to see the function's bounds.

In longer sections of code parentheses can be helpful for visual (human) parsing but I usually favor line breaks for that purpose.  I feel that these are more visible and their purpose more clear.

As alluded to in the second paragraph there *are* of course times that the parentheses are needed, as well as times they *can* improve readability.  There are two different placements and both, sometimes together, have a place.

The first form: `( body & )` is useful for *limiting* the reach of `&`, while the second: `( body ) &` is useful to extend it.  *I feel that reserving them for these purposes makes their meaning more clear.*

One sees from [the precedence table](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) that `&` is fairly far down the list, so a natural reading of `&` is to consider its body to be most things to the left side, bounded by `Set`-type operators or CompoundExpression: `;` (and of course `,`).  (Yes, there are other possible bounds but these are by far the most common in practice.)  Reading my own code if I used `( ... &)` it tells me that the bound needed to be limited, e.g.:

```
5 + (Sqrt[#] &) /@ {1, 2, 3}

Union[list, SameTest -> (Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 3] &)]
```

Conversely if I used `( ... ) &` I know that I wanted to extend the bound, e.g.:

```
(# = #2) & @@@ {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}

$PrePrint = (Print@#; #) &
```

From my perspective sprinkling parentheses needlessly only obfuscates the function of the code and I wish to avoid that, but there is some subjectivity even within these guidelines and I don't mean to imply that parentheses should be used *only* when syntactically necessary.

Consider:

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 888, ! PrimeQ[#1] || ! PrimeQ[#3] &, 3]
```

In my opinion putting `( )` anywhere in the first argument is pointless as this is already as clear as it possibly can be.  The second `&` is a more interesting case.  I would not use the `( body &)` form because as I see it `..., ( stuff ), ...` is redundant:  commas already serve to group expressions so the `( )` tell me nothing.
I might use `( body ) &` if I or someone likely to read the code may not always remember the precedence of `||` versus `&`:

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 888, (! PrimeQ[#1] || ! PrimeQ[#3]) &, 3]
```

Here the `( )` *do* at least tell me something that is not already apparent from the commas: the function body extends through the bounded expression.