# Extracting RHS from Rule

Tags: replacement

In an example from another question, the rhs of a list of rules can be simply extracted:

```
In[1]:= rules1 = Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}][[1]]

              9         3
Out[1]= {x -> -, y -> -(-)}
              2         2

In[2]:= rules1 /. Rule -> (#2 & )

          9    3
 Out[2]= {-, -(-)}
          2    2
```

However, when I try the same replacement with a list of rules where the RHS is a pure function, it does not result in a list of the RHS.

```
In[3]:= rules2 = {MySum -> Total[#1] & , MyProd -> Times[#1] & }

Out[3]= {MySum -> Total[#1] & , MyProd -> Times[#1] & }

In[4]:= rules2 /. Rule -> (#2 & )

Out[4]= {(#2 & )[MySum, Total[#1]] & , (#2 & )[MyProd, Times[#1]] & }
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 4):

Jason shows the solution.  Your input is not in the correct form as in fact the RHS is *not* a "pure function" but rather the *entire rule* is.  Using the methods described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121) will show you this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way to look at this is that `Rule` has a greater binding power than `Function`:

```
Precedence /@ {Rule, Function}
```

> ```
> {120., 90.}
> ```

Also see: [Parentheses in pure functions: # & vs. ( # &)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13120/121)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to make a difference to wrap pure functions inside a set of parentheses, including the ampersand.

```
rules2 = {MySum -> (Total[#1] &), MyProd -> (Times[#1] &)};
rules2 /. Rule -> (#2 &)
```

gives the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
rules2 = {MySum -> Total[#1] &, MyProd -> Times[#1] &}
rules2 /. Rule[_, p_] :> p
(* {Total[#1] &, Times[#1] &} *)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It makes sense why your solution works.  I still can't see why the other version fails.  Your solution seems more general and should work in all cases.  What is it about using a the original patter of just 'Rule' that allowed it to work at all on rules1?

Comment: It should be noted that while this solution works, it does so by taking advantage of the structure of `rules2` (see `FullForm` or `TreeForm`)

Answer (score -1):

This also works:

```
 rules2 = {MySum -> Total[#1] &, MyProd -> Times[#1] &}
 Last /@ rules2
 (* {Total[#1] &, Times[#1] &} *)
```

Comment: The output I get does not match what you show.  I get: `{MySum -> 1, MyProd -> #1}`.  This is no mystery as the `Function` has a body of only one argument so `Last` (or `First`) is simply returning that body, evaluated.  Sorry, but -1.

Comment: As a point of reference you can, in this limited case, get the desired results with `rules2[[All, {1}, 2]]` for the reason described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121) but it is *far* better to enter the expression correctly in the first place.