# User-defined Distance Functions with extra parameters

Tags: functions, function-construction

The `Nearest` function accepts a customized distance function. For example, a simple case that works well is

```
myDist[x_, y_] := Abs[x - y];
data = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1000}], 100];
nf = Nearest[data, DistanceFunction -> myDist]
```

So for instance, the 5 (random) numbers in `data` that are nearest 100 are

```
nf[100, 5]
```

For this particular function, I could have used `DistanceFunction->EuclideanDistance`. But I ultimately need more flexibility, to have a distance function that depends on another parameter. A simple example would be something like

```
myDist2[x_, y_, t_] := If[Abs[x - y] > t, t, Abs[x - y]];
```

where the distance is sort of as before, but if it is above the value of `t`, it returns `t` (the actual function is considerably more complicated, but this one already reveals the problem). The goal is to use `myDist2` in some way -- here are some of the statements that don't work

```
nf = Nearest[data, DistanceFunction -> myDist2[0.5]]
nf = Nearest[data, DistanceFunction -> myDist2[x, y, 0.5]]
nf = Nearest[data, DistanceFunction -> myDist2[#1, #2, 0.5] &]
nf = Nearest[data, DistanceFunction -> myDist2[#1, #2, 0.5]] &
nf = Nearest[data, DistanceFunction -> myDist2[#[[1]], #[[2]], 0.5] &]
```

(I know some of these don't make any syntactic sense, but they show how I was flailing around.) These give a variety of errors, most of which are that the

```
The user-supplied distance function myDist2 does not give a real numeric distance
```

Presumably, these are not calling `myDist2` properly. One fix would be to make the third parameter global, but this is probably a bad idea since it is embedded in a pretty complicated setting. So the question is how to add an extra parameter to the user-specified distance function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got almost there.
Instead of:

```
DistanceFunction -> myDist2[#1, #2, 0.5] &
```

You need to do:

```
DistanceFunction -> (myDist2[#1, #2, 0.5] &)
```

To understand why this parentheses is needed, you can see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13143/2266)

Comment: This is distressingly simple. And the link is both clear (about precedence rules) and your technique of control-dot would have solved my problem (if only I had known about it).

Comment: I've already lost a lot of time for not knowing that too! Glad in help.