# How do I project a list of strings from another list to use in ChartLabels?

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

Say I have the following:

```
dataList = {{"One", 1}, {"Two", 2}};
PieChart[
    #[[2]] & /@ dataList,
    ChartLabels -> #[[1]] & /@ dataList,
    PlotLabel -> "Test plot"
]
```

But while the pie chart is displayed with the correct distribution, the chart labels are not displayed.  This is because the output of

```
#[[2]] & /@ dataList
```

is

```
{One, Two}
```

not

```
{"One", "Two"}
```

I have also tried the following:

```
ChartLabels -> ToString[#[[1]]] & /@ dataList
```

but the outcome is the same as before.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Also related: [Parentheses in pure functions: # & vs. ( # &)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13120)

Comment: Thanks for the links to the related questions.  To those wondering about the answer, without the time to visit the links: simply adding parentheses around the anonymous functions solves the issue.