# A function that only evaluates on lists of pairs

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t PatternTest work with Composition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/why-doesnt-patterntest-work-with-composition)

I'd like my function to only evaluate when the argument is a list of pairs. It seems like `Repeated` and a question mark should work:

```
fourPears[argument_?MatchQ[#, {{_, _} ..}] &]
```

but it does not. What's wrong with this?

Comment: The question mark is called `PatternTest` in this context and is not to be confused with `Information`, which also has a question mark as its short form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the simpler pattern `pairs : {{_, _} ..}`. For example,

```
f[pairs : {{_, _} ..}] := Row[{pairs, " is a list of pairs"}]

f@a
```

> f[a]

```
f@{a}
```

> f[{a}]

```
f@{a, b, {c, d}}
```

> f[{a, b, {c, d}}]

```
f@{{a, w}, {b, x}, {c, y}}
```

> {{a, w}, {b, x}, {c, y}} is a list of pairs

Answer (score 1):

The `?` in this expression (does it have a name?) has high precedence, so it sticks to `argument_` and `MatchQ` more than `MatchQ` sticks to its own arguments. You need parentheses.

```
fourPears[argument_?(MatchQ[#, {{_, _} ..}] &)]
```

should work, but it might not be the best way to accomplish this.