# Question regarding function definition overloading / argument passing test

Tags: function-construction

It is possible to define function dependently to passed argument type or condition this argument fulfills (somewhat like overloading):

```
g[x_?EvenQ] := Print[ToString[x] <> " Is even"]
test1 = (TrueQ[# < 1]) &; test2 := (TrueQ[# >= 1]) &;
g[x_Real ? test1] := Print["function for real x of value < 1"]
g[x_Real? test2] :=Print["function for real x of value >= 1"]
```

Is it possible to use for this purpose lambda function (anonymous function / pure function) so I don't have to define `test1` or `test2` and simply use:

```
g[x_Real ?(TrueQ[# < 1]) &] := Print["function for real x of value < 1"]
g[x_Real ?(TrueQ[# >= 1]) &] :=Print["function for real x of value >= 1"]
```

instead? In first case `g[0.25]` returns `function for real x of value < 1` in second case it remains unevaluated.

Comment: you can also use `/;` (`Condition`).

Comment: Just check the precedence of `?`. Use extra brackets. `g[x_Real ?(TrueQ[# < 1] &)] `

Comment: Both solutions (by Spawn1701D and Rojo)  work, however I needed What Rojo suggested. `g[x_Real ?((TrueQ[# < 1]) &)] := 
 Print["function for real x of value < 1"]`

Comment: Related: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

Comment: @Misery You can leave out the inner `()` and you don't need `TrueQ` because `<` will always give `True/False` for real numerical values and that is guaranteed by your use of `_Real`. In other words, `g[x_Real?(# < 1 &)] := ...` is the same.