# How to correctly use PatternTest (?)

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional, argument-patterns, design-patterns

This works fine:

```
{3, -5, 2, 7, -6, 3} /. x_ /; x < 0 :> 0
(*{3, 0, 2, 7, 0, 3}*)
```

and this works fine:

```
{3, -5, 2, 7, -6, 3} /. _?Negative :> 0
(*{3, 0, 2, 7, 0, 3}*)
```

I am trying to use something like this:

```
{3, -5, 2, 7, -6, 3} /. _?(< 0) :> 0
```

but I am not able to form it correctly.

any idea what is wrong?

Comment: `{3, -5, 2, 7, -6, 3} /. _?(# < 0 &) :> 0`

Comment: See also: [(1699)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699)