# What means the definition F[t_?NumericQ] :=...?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, function-construction

I've come along a function defined in this way:

```
F[t_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{-u''[x] - u[x]/x == -t^2 u[x], u[x0] == x0, u'[x0] == 1}, u, {x, x0, x1}]
```

What does the

```
t_?NumericQ
```

mean and what does it bring us over the use of just F[t_]?

Comment: Please see specifically: [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/121).  If you are confused by the syntax see [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html).  And while you're at it see [(1699)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121).

Comment: Thank you. Just before you posted the comment, I found the answer here: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502 (which is actually a link contained in the first link you mentioned).