# Handling output that was returned unevaluated from a function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, replacement

When evaluating functions, including those described in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-optional-arguments-and-options/1690#1690), how do *Mathematica* users handle values returned from a function that are unevaluated?  For example (based on [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-optional-arguments-and-options/1690#1690)):

```
i[{a_, Longest[b__], c__}] := {"a" -> a, "b" -> {b}, "c" -> {c}} /; Length[{a, b, c}] > 3;
test = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
j=i/@test

(* returns {i[{1, 2}], {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1,  "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}}  *)
```

So the first element of *j* is `i[{1, 2}]` - this is neither the original input `{1,2}` nor in the form of the rest of the output.   Two questions:

a) While it is likely to be application specific, what approaches do others use to handle unevaluated values that are returned?

b)  Is there a generic way to detect unevaluated 'returns' for additional parsing ?

My current thought is to use `Identity` and `ReplaceAll` to eliminate the 'unwanted' function `i`:

```
k=j/.i->Identity
(* returns {{1, 2}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1,   "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}}  *)
```

but this approach requires the name of the function (here *i*) that was evaluated.  Are there any other tricks or approaches to handle this? Am I overlooking benefits to retaining the unevaluated output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "correct way" is to do what is reasonable for *your application*. Depending on the use/needs, you have a few options (not an exhaustive list):

- If you know your input is all going to be of a certain type (e.g. lists), you can tighten your patterns so that you don't end up with invalid input (or what you call "unevaluated output")

  ```
  Clear@i1
  i1[{a_, Longest[b__], c__}] := {"a" -> a, "b" -> {b}, "c" -> {c}} /; Length[{a, b, c}] > 3;
  i1[c : {___}] := "Too short" /; Length[c] <= 3;
  i1 /@ test
  (* {"Too short", {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}} *)
  ```

  Here the assumption is that `"Too short"` means something to your application... it could very well be `Sequence[]`.
- If you don't know what kind of input will be supplied, you can add a down-value/pattern that acts as a default or a fall through pattern. This is generally a good thing to do.

  ```
  Clear@i2
  i2[{a_, Longest[b__], c__}] := {"a" -> a, "b" -> {b}, "c" -> {c}} /; 
     Length[{a, b, c}] > 3;
  i2[___] := "Too short";
  i2 /@ test
  (* {"Too short", {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4},  "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}} *)
  ```
- If you know a priori what type of terms you want or don't want, you can either selectively choose the items or prune the output to get rid of the undesirable terms.

  ```
  Cases[i /@ test, {__Rule}]
  (* {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1,  "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}} *)

  i /@ test /. _i -> Sequence[]
  (* {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1,  "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}} *)
  ```

  As I said, this is only useful if you have some knowledge of the structure (you often do).
- Throw an error or a message.

  ```
  Clear@i3
  i3::invalid = "Invalid entry!";
  i3[{a_, Longest[b__], c__}] := {"a" -> a, "b" -> {b}, "c" -> {c}} /; Length[{a, b, c}] > 3;
  i3[___] /; Message[i3 : invalid] := Null;
  i3 /@ test
  ```

  > Message::name: Message name i3:invalid is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language. >>

  ```
  (* {i3[{1, 2}], {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}}} *)
  ```
- Do nothing. (The implicit assumption is that you either don't care or a subsequent step will handle it correctly.)

Comment: Many thanks, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like `ValueQ[i[#]] & /@ test` which returns a vector corresponding the the results being "real" might be of use?

Comment: thanks.  ValueQ is a new one for me.  According to http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ValueQ.html  Possible Issues, ValueQ returns `True` in the case where the value passed is outside the limit, so I dont think it will work

Comment: @PlaysDice:Yes, I assumed your "unevaluated" meant globally. Perhaps combined with `rm-rf's` excellent suggestions it might still be of use.