# Weird behavior of conditions when using OptionsPattern and OptionValue

Tags: programming, options, conditional

I'm trying to define a function that is evaluated differently depending on its 
options. This code

```
Options[Foo]={Bar->True};
Foo[a_,b_, OptionsPattern[]]:= A /; OptionValue[Bar];
Foo[a_,b_, OptionsPattern[]]:= B /; !OptionValue[Bar];
```

works as expected. Evaluating

```
{Foo[x,y,Bar->True],
Foo[x,y,Bar->False],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->True];
Foo[x,y,Bar->True],
Foo[x,y,Bar->False],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->False];
Foo[x,y,{Bar->True}],
Foo[x,y,{Bar->False}],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->True];
Foo[x,y],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->False];
Foo[x,y]}
```

I get

```
{A, B, A, B, A, B, A, B}
```

which is precisely what I want. However, if I try to make `b` a blank sequence, i.e.

```
Options[Foo]={Bar->True};
Foo[a_,b__, OptionsPattern[]]:= A /; OptionValue[Bar];
Foo[a_,b__, OptionsPattern[]]:= B /; !OptionValue[Bar];
```

weird things start happening. Evaluating my second code sample I get

```
{A, B, A, A, A, B, A, B}
```

which is obviously **wrong**. A possible workaround is to write

```
Options[Foo]={Bar->True};
Foo[a_,b__/;FreeQ[{b},Rule], OptionsPattern[]]:= A /; OptionValue[Bar];
Foo[a_,b__/;FreeQ[{b},Rule], OptionsPattern[]]:= B /; !OptionValue[Bar];
```

However this doesn't seem right to me, since it's actually the job of OptionsPattern to fish out the options from my functions. Of course
I could also write

```
Options[Foo]={Bar->True};
Foo[a_,b__, OptionsPattern[]]:= If[OptionValue[Bar],A,B]
```

which works as well, but this is still another workaround. Moreover, if I want
to have something like (in addition to the regular function definition)

```
Options[Foo]={Bar->True};
Foo[a_,a_,c___, OptionsPattern[]]:= 0 /; OptionValue[Bar];
```

then running

```
{Foo[x,x,Bar->True],
Foo[x,x,Bar->False],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->True];
Foo[x,x,Bar->True],
Foo[x,x,Bar->False],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->False];
Foo[x,x,{Bar->True}],
Foo[x,x,{Bar->False}],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->True];
Foo[x,x],
SetOptions[Foo,Bar->False];
Foo[x,x]}
```

again produces wrong results

```
{0, Foo[x, x, Bar -> False], 0, 0, 0, Foo[x, x, {Bar -> False}], 0, 
 Foo[x, x]}
```

and my only solution is to use

```
Options[Foo]={Bar->True};
Foo[a_,a_,c___/;FreeQ[{c},Rule], OptionsPattern[]]:= 0 /; OptionValue[Bar];
```

which is kind of a hack.

**So my question is, why using conditions with OptionValue and OptionsPattern
works if the last pattern before OptionsPattern is a blank, but fails if it is 
a blank sequence. Is it a bug, or am I missing something essential about OptionsPattern?**

I'm observing this behavior both on Mathematca 9.0.1 and Mathematica 10.0.1 under Linux.

Comment: Is this o.k. for you?`Options[Foo] = {Bar -> True};
Foo[a_, b___, c_ /; ! OptionQ[c], OptionsPattern[]] := 
  A /; OptionValue[Bar];
Foo[a_, b___, c_ /; ! OptionQ[c], OptionsPattern[]] := 
  B /; ! OptionValue[Bar];`

Comment: @rolf This works, thanks. Now I also understand what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Note**: This is an incomplete analysis and leads to the wrong conclusion about the cause of the difficulty. Mr.W's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64193/52) below correctly identifies the culprit as `Condition`.

---

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with `OptionValue`, `OptionsPattern`, or `Condition`. It is simply because `b__` is under specified and `SlotSequence` is greedy.  Effectively, you have specified

```
Foo[a_, b__, c___]
```

so that `b__` will pick up *everything*, including the options, because it hasn't been told not to. The simplest fix is to use `Except`, e.g.

```
Foo[a_, b:Except[_?OptionQ].., OptionsPattern[]]
```

and similarly,

```
Foo[a_, b_, c:Except[_?OptionQ]..., OptionsPattern[]]
```

Note the use of `...` in the second one.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense. I guess I was relying too much on all that magic behind `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue` and started
to ignore the basic pattern matching rules. Shame on me.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason why Mathematica 10.0.1 also accepts `Foo[a_, b_, _:Except[_?OptionQ]..., OptionsPattern[Foo]] := 0 /; OptionValue[Bar]` (however, this function produces wrong results), while Mathematica 9.0.1 immediately complains about `Optional::opdef: "The default value for the optional argument _:Except[_?OptionQ]... contains a pattern."`?

Comment: @vsht `_:Except[_?OptionQ]...` is `pattern:pattern` and that is what it is complaining about. The right hand side of `:` usually should not contain a pattern, hence the message.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't Mathematica 10.0.1 also produce a warning, just like version 9.0.1?

Comment: @vsht likely, but that's not my department. :)

Comment: +1 on your answer however after another look I have a different perspective on this issue.  Please see my answer.

Comment: Note that `test[a_, b__, c___] := {{b}, {c}}; test[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` gives `{{2},{3,4,5,6}}` so that `c` picks up everything, not `b`.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom likely `OptionsPattern[]` is implemented similar to `___?OptionQ` with other tricks added to make it function with `OptionValue`. So, I suspect, with MrW's observations, that when `Condition` fails, it is shifting values from `c` to `b`.

Comment: @rcollyer I think your statement in this answer that "`SlotSequence` is greedy" is completely wrong and misleading: please try `Foo[a_, b__, c___] := {{a}, {b}, {c}}; Foo[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` (output is `{{1}, {2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}`).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I think Mr.W's answer covers it well.

Comment: @rcollyer But isn't it worth to correct your answer? Some time ago I believed it and come to wrong results. It would be fairly at least to add a warning.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I think the solution is workable, but you are correct a warning is needed about the underlying cause being an issue with `Condition` not the pattern's being greedy. Updated.

Answer (score 6):

Alright, I took another look at this issue and I do *not* believe this is a duplicate of:

- [How can I create a function with "positional" or "named" optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/121)

However I also do not believe that rcollyer's analysis is *entirely* correct.  Please consider this example:

```
ClearAll[Foo]
Options[Foo] = {Bar -> True};
Foo[a_, b__, OptionsPattern[]] := If[OptionValue[Bar], A, B]

{Foo[x, y, Bar -> True], Foo[x, y, Bar -> False], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> True];
 Foo[x, y, Bar -> True], Foo[x, y, Bar -> False], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> False];
 Foo[x, y, {Bar -> True}], Foo[x, y, {Bar -> False}], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> True];
 Foo[x, y], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> False];
 Foo[x, y]}
```

> ```
> {A, B, A, B, A, B, A, B}
> ```

Observe that `OptionValue[Bar]` resolves correctly to `True` or `False` in each case.  One can use a more verbose RHS definition to show that every `a_` and `b__` match is correct and that `b__` *does not include the option* as rcollyer stated:

```
ClearAll[Foo]
Options[Foo] = {Bar -> True};
Foo[a_, b__, OptionsPattern[]] := {{a}, {b}, OptionValue[Bar]}

{Foo[x, y, Bar -> True], Foo[x, y, Bar -> False], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> True];
  Foo[x, y, Bar -> True], Foo[x, y, Bar -> False], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> False];
  Foo[x, y, {Bar -> True}], Foo[x, y, {Bar -> False}], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> True];
  Foo[x, y], SetOptions[Foo, Bar -> False];
  Foo[x, y]} // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{True} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{False} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{True} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{False} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{True} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{False} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{True} \\
>  \{x\} & \{y\} & \text{False} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Rather I believe the problem you experienced is due the behavior when a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) fails.  One can see that more than one possible match is checked in this example:

```
ClearAll[Foo]
Options[Foo] = {Bar -> True};
Foo[a_, b__, OptionsPattern[]] := Null /; Print[{{a}, {b}, OptionValue[Bar]}]

Foo[x, y, Bar -> True];
Foo[x, y, {Bar -> False}];
```

> {{x},{y},True}
>
> {{x},{y,Bar->True},True}
>
> {{x},{y},False}
>
> {{x},{y,{Bar->False}},True}

Note that each line results in two different alignments being checked: first the correct one, then an *incorrect* one.  Blocking the incorrect one is how rcollyer's method works, but it is not because `b__` is "greedy" but rather because the first, correct alignment did not pass the `Condition` and another *possible* alignment is sought.  In the second case above the alignment `{{x},{y,{Bar->False}},True}` is the source of error.  (This may be a semantic dispute but I think it is an important one.)

Although I usually favor separate definitions in this case I think using `If` is a more direct solution without unnecessary additional argument testing.

Comment: +1, interesting. It hadn't occurred to me that `Condition` was the real culprit here. As to favoring separate definitions, I'd agree with you, but instead of the `If` form, I'd pass it off to a helper function with different definitions depending on the option value. But, I'd pass it as an argument, not an option to that function.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I like the solution with `If`, but also the one with `Except`, which I think you explain best. This Q&A has been instructive.