# combine two definitions into one

Tags: function-construction, options

Suppose I have two definitions of a function such as

```
arrowAxesXYZ[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
 Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]] &, {a + 2, b + 2, 
    c + 2} IdentityMatrix[3]]

arrowAxesXYZ[{a_, b_, c_}, arrowhead_, arrowstyle_] := {arrowstyle, 
  Arrowheads[arrowhead], 
  Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]] &, {a + 2, b + 2, 
     c + 2} IdentityMatrix[3]]}

Graphics3D@arrowAxesXYZ[{10, 3, 2}, Large, Red]
Graphics3D@arrowAxesXYZ[{10, 3, 2}]
```

[image]

The first function `arrowAxesXYZ[{a, b, c}]` uses the default values `Arroheads` and style of the `Arrow`. The second one `arrowAxesXYZ[{a, b, c}, arrowhead, arrowstyle]` uses the values given by the user.

How can I compine the two definitions into one? I am familiar with `Default` but I don't know how it can be used here.

Thanks.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-optional-arguments-and-options

Comment: @dimitris: Why do you need to combine the two definitions into one?

Comment: I thought it was a good idea than having two separate definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear@arrowAxesXYZ

arrowAxesXYZ[{a_, b_, c_}, arrowhead_: Automatic, arrowstyle_: {}] :=
 {arrowstyle, Arrowheads[arrowhead],
  Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]] &, {a + 2, b + 2, c + 2} IdentityMatrix[3]]}

Graphics3D @ arrowAxesXYZ[{10, 3, 2}, Large, Red]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D @ arrowAxesXYZ[{10, 3, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: With `Graphics3D @ arrowAxesXYZ[{10, 3, 2}, Red]` for instance I got error messages.

Comment: In this case you must write `Graphics3D@arrowAxesXYZ[{10, 3, 2}, Automatic, Red]`

Comment: Thanks again. (Sorry for the mistake).