# Overriding default value of inheritied option as per passed options

Tags: options, default

Consider the following example that shows the spirit of my problem:

```
ClearAll@"r`myPlot";
Options[r`myPlot] = {myOnlyOption -> 1};
r`myPlot[someArgs___, opts : OptionsPattern[{r`myPlot, Graphics}]] := 
 Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, OptionValue@"myOnlyOption"],
  Axes -> True(*default is to show axes*),
  FilterRules[{opts}, Options@Graphics]
  ]
r`myPlot[Axes -> False](*user overrode but axes will still show*)
```

`r'myPlot` shows a `Circle` of radius `myOnlyOption`. Any other `Graphics`' setting, the user *may* pass. When the user doesn't, some default behaviour is implemented.

1. How to achieve this behaviour wherein a user may modify the value of some inherited options which when the user doesn't bother to set, get set to some default values?

Eg. the default behaviour is to show the axes. However, if the user deems so, they may be hidden. As seen in the output of above, this doesn't happen. Effectively the command being executed is `Graphics[...,Axes->True,Axes->False]` wherein repetitions get ignored and that is the problem.

Comment: Change the order? Put the defaults after the user opts?

Comment: @MichaelE2 sry, I didn't understand...as in [....,opts:OptionsPattern[...],showAxes_Boolean]?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yep got it  and works (*faceapalms*)

Comment: Related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/58370

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi yeah I had gone there..it solves a diff. problem though