# Condition (/;) not working correctly on a function with optional arguments and options

Tags: function-construction, options, conditional, optional-arguments

I have read this post: [How to avoid collision between optional arguments and options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/62417), and use [Mr.Wizard's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1690/62417) to solve this problem. But when I add conditions to optional arguments, it seems that conditions have been repeatedly judged.

```
f[x_, Shortest[y_ : 1, 1], Shortest[z_ : 11, 2], 
    OptionsPattern[{"g" -> Identity, "h" -> (#^2 &)}]] /; 
   If[MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, y], 
    If[MemberQ[{11, 12, 13}, z], True, Print[Style[{x, y, z}, Red]]; 
     False], Print[Style[{x, y, z}, Red]]; False] := 
  OptionValue["h"][OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]];
```

```
In[1]:= f[0]
Out[1]= 144

In[2]:= f[0, 1]
Out[2]= 144

In[3]:= f[0, 4]
{0, 4, 11}
{0, 1, 4}
Out[3]= f[0, 4]

In[4]:= f[0, 1, 11]
Out[4]= 144

In[5]:= f[0, 1, 14]
{0, 1, 14}
Out[5]= f[0, 1, 14]

In[6]:= f[1, "g" -> Sqrt]
Out[6]= 13

In[7]:= f[0, 13]
{0, 13, 11}
Out[7]= 196
```

If conditions are judged inside function, it works normally (I'm not sure).

```
f[x_, Shortest[y_ : 1, 1], Shortest[z_ : 11, 2], 
   OptionsPattern[{"g" -> Identity, "h" -> (#^2 &)}]] := 
  If[MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, y], 
   If[MemberQ[{11, 12, 13}, z], 
    OptionValue["h"][OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]], 
    Print[Style[{x, y, z}, Red]]; False], 
   Print[Style[{x, y, z}, Red]]; False];
```

```
In[1]:= f[0]
Out[1]= 144

In[2]:= f[0, 1]
Out[2]= 144

In[3]:= f[0, 4]
{0, 4, 11}
Out[3]= False

In[4]:= f[0, 1, 11]
Out[4]= 144

In[5]:= f[0, 1, 14]
{0, 1, 14}
Out[5]= False

In[6]:= f[1, "g" -> Sqrt]
Out[6]= 13

In[7]:= f[0, 13]
{0, 13, 11}
Out[7]= False
```

My goal is to get the optional arguments in order, if conditions are not met, return the unevaluated expression like built-in functions and print error message only once.

````
In[1]:= f[0, 4]
error message
Out[1]= f[0, 4]

In[2]:= f[0, 4, 11]
error message
Out[2]= f[0, 4, 11]

In[3]:= f[0, 4, 14]
error message
Out[3]= f[0, 4, 14]

In[4]:= f[0, 4, "g" -> Sqrt]
error message
Out[4]= f[0, 4, "g" -> Sqrt]
```
````

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to get the optional arguments in order, if conditions are not met, return the unevaluated expression like built-in functions and print error message only once.

The trick with [`Shortest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html) seems fragile to me, and can easily be avoided in this case by writing better patterns for the `y` and `z` variables

```
f[x_, y : 1 | 2 | 3 : 1, z : 11 | 12 | 13 : 11,
    OptionsPattern[{"g"->Identity, "h"->(#1^2&)}]] := OptionValue["h"][OptionValue["g"][x + y + z]];
f[args__] := (
    Print["message for bad arguments ", {args}];
    Null /; False
)
```

I believe this passes all the requirements.